# Insert Data into Database (Android Studio)

Tags: android, sql, database, insert

I am trying to do an app where you have an account and you have to login to use the app. So obviously you need to register for the app. The problem is when I enter the sign up form and enter all the details, the data doesn't go into the database. Any help?

Reference used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxlLsk5j3rY

This is the method to insert the contact into the database.

```
public void insertContact(Account a)
{

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String query = "select * from users";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    values.put(COLUMN_ID,count);
    values.put(COLUMN_FirstName, a.getFirstname());
    values.put(COLUMN_LastName, a.getLastname());
    values.put(COLUMN_Username, a.getUsername());
    values.put(COLUMN_Password, a.getPassword());
    values.put(COLUMN_Email, a.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_ClubName, a.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_Address, a.getAddress());


    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    Log.e("Contact Entered", "DATABASE");
    db.close();
}
```

The Register Button event

```
public void onRegisterClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnregister) {
        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        EditText lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtlastname);
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
        EditText clubname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtclubname);
        EditText address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtaddress);

        //Text entered in the textview is assigned to a variable and to string
        String namestr = name.getText().toString();
        String lastnamestr = lastname.getText().toString();
        String userstr = username.getText().toString();
        String passstr = password.getText().toString();
        String emailstr = email.getText().toString();
        String clubnamestr = clubname.getText().toString();
        String addresssrt = address.getText().toString();


        Account a = new Account();
        a.setFirstname(namestr);
        a.setLastname(lastnamestr);
        a.setUsername(userstr);
        a.setPassword(passstr);
        a.setEmail(emailstr);
        a.setClubname(clubnamestr);
        a.setAddress(addresssrt);

        datab.insertContact(a);
        Log.e("insertContact(a)", "DATABASE");
        Toast temp = Toast.makeText(CreateAccount.this, "Account created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        temp.show();

        Intent i = new Intent(CreateAccount.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No, it works smoothly.

Comment: try debugging, you probably put a listener to a wrong button, or there is wrong ID on the button, or..., or..., or 1000 more causes.

Comment: Random thought, do you have auto commit set to false in your SQLite?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, didn't specify. So I assume it's set to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use SuperDatabase to control your database with pure SQL. I've created a library to make things easier on Android. Import library to Gradle and use SuperDatabase.

Documentations here : https://github.com/sangeethnandakumar/TestTube

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Adding BeginTransaction() and SetTransactionSuccessful helped.

```
public void insertContact(Account a)
{

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
db.beginTransaction();
String query = "select * from users";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
int count = cursor.getCount();

values.put(COLUMN_ID,count);
values.put(COLUMN_FirstName, a.getFirstname());
values.put(COLUMN_LastName, a.getLastname());
values.put(COLUMN_Username, a.getUsername());
values.put(COLUMN_Password, a.getPassword());
values.put(COLUMN_Email, a.getEmail());
values.put(COLUMN_ClubName, a.getEmail());
values.put(COLUMN_Address, a.getAddress());


db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
Log.e("Contact Entered", "DATABASE");
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
}
```